# Select total count from one table when field isn't found matching in another table

Tags: mysql

My apologies if the title is a bit confusing.  Hopefully this description will help.

I have a database table recording *page views* on my site.  Each record is stamped with the users IP Address and the time of their visit (along with other details).

I have another separate database table which contains a list of *IP Addresses* that will be used for testing, etc.

I would like to select a total count of the visits in the first table **but only when the IP Address is not found in the other table**.  This way I can automatically hide testing data.

Is this possible in one query or will I have to retrieve all results and then separately check each one against the testing IP addresses?

Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t1.ip, count(t1.timestamp) 
from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.ip = t2.ip
where t2.ip is null
group by t1.ip
```

will give a the visit count for every IP that is not in the other table.

Comment: Awesome that's perfect thanks, I'll mark it as answered as soon as it'll let me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the tables using `LEFT JOIN` since you want to count for `IPAdd` that did not exist on the other table.

```
SELECT  a.IPAdd, COUNT(a.IPAdd) totalCount
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.IPAdd = b.IPAdd
WHERE   b.IPAdd IS NULL
GROUP   BY a.IPAdd
```

Alternatively, you could also use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.IPAdd, COUNT(a.IPAdd) totalCount
FROM    Table1 a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  null
            FROM    Table2 b
            WHERE   a.IPAdd = b.IPAdd
        )
GROUP   BY a.IPAdd
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT 
    count(*) 
FROM 
    (SELECT
        tbl.ip
    FROM
        tbl
    LEFT JOIN 
        testingTable
    ON
        tbl.ip = testingTable.ip AND testingTable.ip is null)tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a left outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM `pageViews`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ipAddresses` ON `pageViews`.`ipAddress = `ipAddresses`.`ipAddress`
WHERE `ipAddresses`.`ipAddress` IS NULL
```